# Return HUD key from Mod 2 + Alt L back to Alt L

Tags: shortcut-keys, hud

I was fooling around in the keyboard shortcut section, and accidentally **changed the HUD's shortcut from  Alt L to Mod 2 + Alt L.**

Now, whenever I hold and even press the alt key, HUD will pop up. I don't have the option to hold the alt key, and then press F4 to close a window.

[image]

How can I get this back to normal? Every time I try too, I can never get the shortcut back to just Alt L.

Comment: Here is an easier way. Make sure, Num Lock is NOT set. Now, set HUD display keyboard shortcut and you are done :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CompizConfig Settings Manager to change the key used to show the Unity HUD.

To open terminal hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Or search for 'compizconfig-settings-manager' and install it from there.

Once installed, Hit Super key (Windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "ccsm" and open it.

In CompizConfig Settings Manager Navigate to `Desktop` > `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`

Under the Behavior tab click on little cross in front of "Key to show the HUD", This will set the key to default (<kbd>Alt</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Due to a bug described here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/981628

you can't change HUD key from mod2+ ALt L back to Alt L.

The solution is quite simple, just turn NumLock off and try again.

You'll find the default setting is back again!

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a million, I've been solving this for an hour! In my case it was for Alt+Shift for keyboard layout change. Adding this comment for search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign any key combination you like by simply clicking the row that reads "Key to show the HUD". Then the shortcut text will change to "New accelerator...". Then just press the left "Alt" key. ("Alt L" stands for your left Alt key.)