# Problem in keyboard text entry shortcuts

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Every time I assign a shortcut a `Mod2` button appears (as in the picture) and I can't find it in the keyboard. The short cut does not work, and this appears in addition to the keys I am actually pressing

[image]

Comment: it appears when i press shift+ctrl l

Comment: no i'm sure. it's the first time i see that!

Comment: Do you have a NumPad?

Comment: @Zanna No it does not

Comment: @Raphael yes, it's a standard laptop keyboard.

Comment: @Haythem - Try turning off your NumPad and assigning key again.

Comment: Your solution - http://askubuntu.com/a/311357/119531